# dojo automatic textbox select

Tags: text, textbox, dojo

Dojo newbie here and I have a dialog and before I dialog.show(), I want to fully set and select one of the text boxes.  The select() is not available as I have tried.  As an extension I need to select the entire textbox contents on any click in any textbox after the dialog is up.  I cannot seem to get around the missing select().  How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `selectOnClick` attribute on `TextBox` that should help you out there:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" 
       data-dojo-props="selectOnClick:true"
       value="Everything is selected on click"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/v97wgxLb/

If you want to programmatically set focus and set the selection, you could cheat and call the private `_onFocus` method directly. Looks like you'd pass in the string `"mouse"`, e.g.

```
myTextBox._onFocus("mouse");
```

Comment: I am showing the dialog, then calling functions on the textBoxs in a switch and in that case for that payment type I am trying the cheat and it does not select, just put cursor at the end.  Ideas